# R nls function and starting values

Tags: statistics, time-series

I'm wondering how I can find/choose the starting values for the nls function as I'm getting errors with any I put in. I also want to confirm that I can actually use the nls function with my data set as I am recording data for weeks in a single year the below are 31 weeks of data.

```
    data
 [1] 108 128  93  96 107 126 105 137  78 117 111 131 106 123 112  90  79 106 120
[20]  91 100 103 112 138  61  57  97 100  95  92  78

week = (1:31)
```

R code for nls function

```
> data.fit = nls(data~M*(((P+Q)^2/P)*exp((P+Q)*week)/(1+(Q/P)*exp(-(P+Q)*week))^2), start=c(M=?, P=?, Q=?))
```

Comment: Statistics questions are better asked at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), programming questions at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a rather long comment.

It is perfectly understandable that any solver would have a lot of trouble for the fit of such a complex model without providing more than reasonable estimates for parameters $P,Q,M$.

I did want want to work with the data you posted but looking  at the model, what we could notice is that $$F(0)=MP$$ $$F'(0)= M P (P+3 Q)$$ Moreover $F(x)$ goes through an extremum value when $$x=\frac{1}{P+Q}\log \left(-\frac{3 Q}{P}\right)$$ So, if the data did not containing errors and the values at $x=0$ were available, probably exploiting these three fact could lead to some resonable estimates.